# Upgraded to aws-sdk V2, and now presigned URL's are failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, pre-signed-url

I used to write this to generate a presigned URL in aws-sdk V1 :

```
AWS.config(S3Config::S3_CONFIG)
bucket = AWS.s3.buckets[S3Config::S3_CONFIG[:bucket]]
presigned_url = bucket.presigned_post(
  key: "attachments/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}",
  success_action_status: 201, acl: 'public-read'
)
```

Which sent an OPTIONS/POST **working** request like this :

https://gist.github.com/gotoAndBliss/cdd8818b8adce58d1b625f68e2633199

The biggest difference is that the **Status Code** is  `201 Created`

I then updated to V2 and rewrote it to this :

```
presigned_url = Aws::S3::PresignedPost.new(aws_creds, aws_region, S3Config::BUCKET, {
  key: "attachments\/#{SecureRandom.uuid}\/\${filename}",
  metadata: {"original-filename" => "${filename}"},
  acl: 'public-read', success_action_status: ['201']
})
```

To which I'm pretty sure was properly written. But this generates this request :

https://gist.github.com/gotoAndBliss/43a4a88adc5c2be0b70b66d551a72a84

The biggest difference is the **Status Code** : `204 No Content`

I went through this line for line and it seems like *everything* else is identical. Would anyone know why these are failing? Or what sets them apart?

Comment: why isn't your second example using `success_action_status: '201'` ?

Comment: @Anthony I'm guessing that's proper formatting? It doesn't seem to accept integers in V2

Comment: the docs say it takes a string.

Comment: @Anthony As a string, I get the same results.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Below is my process for doing presigned uploads. One thing I'm noticing right off the bat is you are escaping the `/` in your key. I don't and it works fine. I use ENV variables for the secret stuff.

config/initializers/aws.rb:

```
Aws.config.update(
  {region: 'us-west-2',
   credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
   ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']),
  }
)

S3_BUCKET = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'])
```

In my controller I generate the url like this:

```
@s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(
  key: "my_bucket_folder/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", 
  success_action_status: '201', 
  acl: 'public-read')
```